# How to access model's data controller inside directive with these has defined with "this"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm confusing with the access data with a directive, specifically when a I have defined my models like:

```
vm = this;
vm.myModel = "hello";
```

And my directive:

```
function mySelectedAccount(){
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.on('click', function() {
            console.log(scope.myModel);                
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

**Since I'm not using $scope, how across the directive can I access to "myModel" defined inside my controller?** If I try to access it with ***scope*** parameter inside my directive I get undefined.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, your `vm` variable refers to your controller instance. In your scope, you register the controller context into the `vm` variable.

So you can do :

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope) {

  var vm = this;
  vm.myModel = 'toto';

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**Directive**

```
(function(){

  function directive() {
    return {
      link:function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.on('click', function() {
          //Access to vm property wrap into the scope
          console.log(scope.vm.myModel);
        });
      }
    };
  }

angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('directive', directive);

})();
```

Then in your html, you can use the **controllerAs** syntax :

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
    <div directive>{{vm.myModel}}</div>
  </body>
```

You can see here the [**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/aaHlcJ8tC6w7xAIJPgEg?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much! It was very helpful your answer! :)